# when does open(2) fail with errno == EMLINK?

Tags: c, posix, freebsd, errno

i came across a bit of code which says

```
int fd = open(fn, flags, 0);
if (fd < 0 && errno != EMLINK)
  ...
```

`flags` is either `O_RDONLY` or `O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW`

IEEE Std 1003.1, 2013 (SUSv4) has just

- [EMLINK]
  Too many links. An attempt was made to have the link count of a single file exceed {LINK_MAX}.
- {LINK_MAX}
  Maximum number of links to a single file.

how does opening a file increase its link count?

Comment: I don't see `EMLINK` listed as one of the possible errors for [`open`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html). It is listed for [`link`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/link.html) though.

Comment: @Sander because you're looking at the linux manpages!

Comment: @NicholasWilson: No, same for the POSIX specifications themselfs. See *Jean-Baptiste Yunès* answer below.

Comment: @NicholasWilson : click the links in my comment, and you'll find I'm not looking at linux manpages, but at the 2013 edition of POSIX.1-2008, which is the standard mentioned by the op.

Comment: this code originates in FreeBSD, sorry to have withheld this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question. When `O_NOFOLLOW` was added, they chose to reuse an existing error code rather than make up a new one. `EMLINK` in this case signifies that the file is a symlink and is returned on FreeBSD. Linux and Darwin return `ELOOP` rather than `EMLINK`, while NetBSD uses `EFTYPE`.

My manpages say `O_NOFOLLOW` is a FreeBSD extension subsequently added to Linux (ie you won't find its behaviour explained in older versions of the SUS, but it is included in the POSIX 2008 with the Linux return code).

Comment: `ELOOP` will be returned when following too many symbolic links or when `O_NOFOLLOW` is specified.

Comment: There is a NetBSD discussion at http://gnats.netbsd.org/43154 about the overloading of this existing code adopted by FreeBSD (although NetBSD were debating about using EFTYPE or ELOOP instead)

Comment: POSIX says ELOOP is the error when you specify a symlink and O_NOFOLLOW is included; Linux may implement EMLINK following BSD, in which case neither Linux nor BSD is POSIX-compliant.  However, Mac OS X documents ELOOP as the error when you open a symlink with O_NOFOLLOW.

Comment: @Edward corrected, just checked on a Linux system :)

Comment: @NicholasWilson you may have gotten a downvote because `O_NOFOLLOW` *is* specified for `open(2)`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html (it says `errno` is set to `ELOOP` then).

Comment: @NicholasWilson Right you are, I didn't realize they had reused `EMLINK` in this way on the FreeBSD.

Answer (score 2):

This is not specified by SUS v4. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html

Comment: You are right I've made a mistake, this is just not specified sorry.

Comment: +1: does not answer my question, but is an appropriate response given the initial lack of the [freebsd] tag nevertheless.  thanks for your effort!